# Running a terminal program from java and saves it to a file called output1.txt

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class RunInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Island < island1.in");
            p.waitFor();

            InputStream in = p.getInputStream();



            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(b);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I could not figure out why my program doesn't seem to run the command line and save it to output1.txt. Can someone tell me what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: do you get any exceptions

Comment: Why are you waiting for the process to finish before reading? This is not needed. Also, did you try a debugger?

Comment: Do you close/flash output stream anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

There are I think 2 things missing:

1. you need to set the classpath for your Java command
2. you need toseparate the arguments of the command line you want to execute

For instance, assuming the classpath is the current directory:

```
String[] commands = { "java", "-cp", ".", "Island", "< island1.in" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

Comment: This is actually a [convenience overload](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

[`Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29) does not execute the given command in a shell, so redirection via `<` and `>` will not work as you expect.  Instead, they will be passed as additional parameters to the executed command.  Use the [`getOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and [`getInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) methods of the `Process` object returned by `exec` instead.

Don't be confused by the names: `getOutputStream` returns the standard *input* stream of the subprocess (which is of type `java.io.OutputStream`) while `getInputStream` returns the standard *output* stream of the subprocess (which is of type `java.io.InputStream`).  In my humble opinion these methods were better named `getStandardInput`, `getStandardOutput` and `getStandardError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without invoking a seperate Java VM with code like this:

```
    System.setIn(new FileInputStream("island1.in"));
    System.setOut(new FileOutputStream("output1.txt"));
    new Island().main(new String[0]);
```

This replaces the "stdin" and "stdout" with your files and then invokes the main of the `Island` class.